# A uniformly continuous function on a bounded set whose image is not bounded?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

I'm trying to find an example of a uniformly continuous function $f:X\to Y$ such that $f(X)$ is not bounded, for some bounded metric space $X$ and a metric space $Y$.

The classic exercise is to show that if $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is bounded then any uniformly continuous $f$ sends bounded sets onto bounded sets, this is because such sets are totally bounded in this case.

So what is an example of a bounded metric space $X$, not totally bounded, such that a uniformly continuous function sends it to a not bounded set?

Comment: Try $X=\mathbb{Z}$ with the discrete metric.

Comment: @user10354138 I see, thank you